# mysql Field 'col1' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql

I had db schema defined as below

```
CREATE TABLE `ATestTable` (
    id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    refId varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    col1 text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `unique_keyy_refId` (`refId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=123 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

when I have something like this

```
Insert into ATestTable (refId, col1) Values ('abc', 'def');
```

I got error `Field 'col1' doesn't have a default value`. I searched online this error should happens when there is no value specified for this NOT NULL column. But I do specified the value. I even tried the same insert script on my local db and it works. So is it a db server configuration thing?

I run `show variables like '%sql_mode%'` and the one which doesn't work is `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`. My local db (which works) is giving me `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Comment: The error can't be coming from that line. You must have something else that's inserting without providing a value for `col1`.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a trigger on this or another table which is inserting into this table?

Comment: @Nick， could u please make ur comment to an answer. so i can accept it.

Comment: @Laodao I'm glad that solved your problem but there's probably not enough information I could put in an answer to make it useful to other users. Thanks for the offer though.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can try, in other to fix your issue

1) You can change the sql mode to match your local db mode by running this query

```
    SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'modes';
```

modes separated by comma's. Note that this will work if only you have administrative rights. If not use

```
    SET SESSION sql_mode = 'modes';
```

which will affect only the current client.

2) Set a default value for Col1 (eg: empty text) and the trigger will update the value anyways

```
   CREATE TABLE `ATestTable` (
   id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   refId varchar(32) NOT NULL,
   col1 text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT ' ' not.  
   NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `unique_keyy_refId` (`refId`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=123 DEFAULT.    
   CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```